# opacity value for my C# form isn't adjusting

Tags: c#, winforms, opacity

I wanted to make one of my forms opaque. I did this by changing the opacity value in the form between 0 and 100. I later wanted to change this value during run-time, so i wrote some code:

```
Opacity = 80;
```

However my form doesn't seem to change opacity. Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure enough to write as an answer, but I believe opacity is from 0 to 1, so you'd want 0.80, though I could be confusing myself with UWP.

Comment: @gilliduck, you are correct and you should post as an answer. Opacity works between 0 and 1. so a value of 0.8 is correct.

Comment: @HandbagCrab thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Form.Opacity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.opacity) property ranges from 0 to 1. So to achieve 80% opacity, you would write `Opacity = 0.8`

Comment: Thank you so much, kind of confusing how it works like that